# How to add legend to a CausalImpact plot object

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using the CausalImpact package, developed by Google folks, to assess the causal impact of an intervention in a time series.

[See the documentation for more info](https://google.github.io/CausalImpact/CausalImpact.html#using-a-custom-model).

I created a plot, like in the example. And I'd like to add a legend, like we find [here](http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/pt-BR//pubs/archive/41854.pdf), in page 249.

I know that using the function plot (of CausalImpact package) produces a ggplot2 object. However, I don't know how to add a legend.

Some reproducible data:

```
library(devtools)
devtools::install_github("google/CausalImpact")
library(CausalImpact)

set.seed(1)
x1 <- 100 + arima.sim(model = list(ar = 0.999), n = 100)
y <- 1.2 * x1 + rnorm(100)
y[71:100] <- y[71:100] + 10
data <- cbind(y, x1)
pre.period <- as.Date(c("2014-01-01", "2014-03-11"))
post.period <- as.Date(c("2014-03-12", "2014-04-10"))
time.points <- seq.Date(as.Date("2014-01-01"), by = 1, length.out = 100)
data <- zoo(cbind(y, x1), time.points)
impact <- CausalImpact(data, pre.period, post.period)
plot(impact)
```

Comment: Your code does not run as is. I get: `Error in FormatInputPrePostPeriod(pre.period, post.period, data) : 
  pre.period (numeric) and post.period (numeric) should have the same class as the time points in the data (Date)`

Comment: Sorry. I fixed the example. It should work now.

Comment: OK. So what do you want in the legend??

Comment: Something like page 249 of the report linked. I.e., the names of the series and the type of lines.

Comment: `CausalImpact:::CreateImpactPlot` shows you the code used by the plot method. It's a ggplot, but with no colour mapping. I suspect the plots of page 249 weren't made with this function, but with base graphics. You're probably better off writing your own, maybe based on `CreateImpactPlot`.

Answer (score 1):

To add further elements the plot (I think this is what you have in mind), you will need to adapt the function:

```
CausalImpact:::CreateImpactPlot
```

See [here](https://github.com/google/CausalImpact/blob/master/R/impact_plot.R#L91) for the source code.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can create your own plot using the data in `impact[["series"]]`